# EJS templates including functions

Tags: ejs

I'm using EJS templates and trying to organize some functions that are defined within EJS.  For example let's say I have a simple function within a template:

```
<%
  const getItems = () => {}
%>
```

This perfectly fine when it's being used on the same page it's defined.  However, if I want to move this into say a generic `functions.ejs` then in other pages `<%- include(functions) %>` the `getItems` is undefined.

Would anyone know a way to include re-usable functions within ejs?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, this might have much to do with how and where you call that `functions.ejs` file. You should render it within other templates' variable scope, perhaps using the directive `<% include('functions') %>` above other code you wish the scope of `functions.ejs` to be reached.

For example, you might have two different EJS template files: `functions.ejs` and `other_functions.ejs`, and want to call them from a third template file. An option to do so would be:

```
    <!-- Bla bla bla -->
    <% include('functions') %>
    <!-- stuff using 'functions.ejs' code -->
    <% include('other_functions') %>
    <!-- stuff inside of 'other_functions.ejs' calling 'functions.ejs' code -->
```

So in the end, the result could be:

```
    <!-- Bla bla bla -->
    const getItems = () => {}
    <!-- stuff using 'functions.ejs' code -->
    var items = getItems()
    <!-- stuff inside of 'other_functions.ejs' calling 'functions.ejs' code -->
```

Please let me know if I'm helping you to see a solution.